# Error while trying to make stripe payment in React js

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, stripe-payments, mern

I am trying to develop an online shopping web application using MERN. While implementing Stripe Payment am getting the following error in the server terminal as well as console:
"You did not provide an API key. You need to provide your API key in the Authorization header, using Bearer auth (e.g. 'Authorization: Bearer YOUR_SECRET_KEY').
See https://stripe.com/docs/api#authentication for details, or we can help at [https://support.stripe.com/."](https://support.stripe.com/.%22)
I have provided both the test API keys correctly, I have verified them many times don't understand why this error still coming.

```
    //This is my PaymentRouter.ts code:

import express from 'express';
import tokenVerifier from '../middlewares/tokenVerifier';
import cors from "cors";
import {v4} from "uuid";

interface PaymentBody{
    product: {
        name?: string;
        amount?: number;
        currency?: string;
    },
    customer: {
        name?: string;             
        address? : {
            line1?: string;
            postal_code?: string;
            city?: string;
            state?: string;
            country?: string;
            };
    },
    description?: string;
    email? : string;
    source?: string;
    stripetokenType?:string;
}
const paymentRouter:express.Router = express.Router();
const stripe = require('stripe')(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY);

/*
   @usage : checkout payment
   @url : /api/v1/payments/checkout
   @fields : paymentBody
   @method : post
   @access : PRIVATE
 */

paymentRouter.post('/checkout', tokenVerifier, cors(), async (request : express.Request , response : express.Response) => {
    try{
        console.log(request.body);
        let userObj:any = request.headers['user'];
        let userId = userObj.id;
        const paymentBody:PaymentBody = request.body;
        const newCustomer = await stripe.customers.create(
            {
                name : paymentBody.customer.name,
                address : {
                    line1: paymentBody.customer.address.line1,
                    postal_code: paymentBody.customer.address.postal_code,
                    city: paymentBody.customer.address.city,
                    state: paymentBody.customer.address.state,
                    country: paymentBody.customer.address.country
                    },
            description : paymentBody.description,
            email : paymentBody.email,
            source: paymentBody.source,
            metadata: {
                userId: userId,
                },
            });

        if(paymentBody.stripetokenType==='card'){
            const idempotencyKey = v4();
            const paymentCharge = await stripe.charges.create({
                amount: paymentBody.product.amount,
                currency: paymentBody.product.currency,
                customer : newCustomer.id,                                        
                description: paymentBody.description                
            }, {idempotencyKey});
        }
        else{
            throw Error(`Unrecognized Stripe token type: "${paymentBody.stripetokenType}"`);
        }
        response.status(200).json({msg : 'payment is successful', customer: newCustomer.id});   
    }
    catch(error){
        console.error(error);
        response.status(400).json({errors : [{msg : error.message}]});                                                            
    }
});

export default paymentRouter;
```

```
    //My react checkoutPage.tsx: page code:

import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import {NavLink, useHistory} from 'react-router-dom';
import StripeCheckout from 'react-stripe-checkout';
import stripeImage from '../../assets/img/LuckyClove.png'
import * as orderActions from '../../redux/orders/order.actions';
import * as orderReducer from '../../redux/orders/order.reducer';
import * as userActions from '../../redux/users/user.actions';
import * as userReducer from '../../redux/users/user.reducer';

const taxPercent:number = 5.0;

const reactstripeKey: string | undefined = process.env.REACT_APP_STRIPE_KEY;

interface IProps{}

interface IuserState{
    userKey : userReducer.userState;
}
interface IorderState{
    orderKey : orderReducer.orderState;
}

let CheckOutPage:React.FC<IProps> = ({}) => {

    let history = useHistory();
    let dispatch = useDispatch();
// get user Address info from Store
    let userStore:userReducer.userState = useSelector((store: IuserState) => {
        return store.userKey;
    });
// get cart details
    let orderStore: orderReducer.orderState = useSelector((store: IorderState) => {
        return store.orderKey;
    });

    let {user , loading} = userStore;
    let {cartItems} = orderStore;

// calculate total
    let totalAmount = ():number=>{
        let total=0;
            for(let item of cartItems){
                total += Number(item.qty) * Number(item.price);
            }
            return total;
        }
    
    let taxAmount:number = (taxPercent/100 * totalAmount());
    let grandTotal = ():number =>{
        return (totalAmount() + taxAmount)
    }

    let items:any = cartItems.map(item =>{
        return{
            name: item.name,
            brand: item.brand,
            size: item.size,
            qty: item.qty,
            price: item.price
        }
    })

    let order:any = {
        items : items,
        tax:taxAmount,
        total: grandTotal()
    }

    let handleToken = async (token?:any , addresses?:any)=>{
        const body = {
            product: {
                name: `${cartItems[0].name}..`,
                amount: grandTotal() * 100,
                currency: 'INR'
            },
            customer: {
                name : addresses.billing_name,
                address : {
                    line1: addresses.billing_address_line1,
                    postal_code: addresses.billing_address_zip,
                    city: addresses.billing_address_city,
                    state: addresses.billing_address_state,
                    country: addresses.billing_address_country
                    },
            },
            description: 'shopping with Jing-Dong',
            email : token.email,
            source: token.id,
            stripetokenType:token.type
        }
        dispatch(orderActions.makestripePayment(body, order, history));
    }

    return(
        <React.Fragment>
            <section className="mt-2" >
                <div className="container">
                    <h3 className='text-success'> Proceed Check-out</h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Impedit error ab, vel minima sed modi reiciendis. Id, incidunt. Nobis eos culpa similique dicta aliquid id itaque inventore minus sapiente tempora!</p>
                </div>            
            </section> 
            <section className="mt-2" >
                <div className="container">
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="col-md-6">
                            <div className="card">
                                <div className="card-header bg-dark text-white">
                                    <p>Shipping Address <NavLink to='/users/profile/address' className='float-end fa fa-edit mx-2 text-white'/> </p>
                                </div>
                                <div className="card-body">
                                    <ul className='list-group' >
                                        <li className='list-group-item list-group-item-success'>
                                             Name: <small className='fw-bold'>{user.name}</small><br/>
                                             Flat: <small className='fw-bold'>{user.address?.flat}</small><br/>
                                             Street: <small className='fw-bold'>{user.address?.street}</small><br/>
                                             Landmark: <small className='fw-bold'>{user.address?.landmark}</small><br/>
                                             City: <small className='fw-bold'>{user.address?.city}</small><br/>
                                             State: <small className='fw-bold'>{user.address?.state}</small><br/>
                                             Country: <small className='fw-bold'>{user.address?.country}</small><br/>
                                             Pin: <small className='fw-bold'>{user.address?.pin}</small><br/> 
                                             Phone Number: <small className='fw-bold'>{user.address?.phone}</small>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div className="card">
                                <div className="card-header bg-dark text-white">
                                    <p>Mode of Payment</p>
                                </div>
                                <div className="card-body">
                                    <ul className='list-group'>
                                        <li className='list-group-item list-group-item-success'>                                            
                                            <input type='radio' value='Credit card Payment' defaultChecked name='paymentMode'  className='mx-2'/>
                                            <i className="fab fa-cc-stripe mx-1"/>Credit card Payment<br/>
                                        </li>                                        
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-md-6">
                            <div className="card">
                                    <div className="card-header bg-dark text-white">
                                        <p>Review order details</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="card-body">
                                        <ul className='list-group'>
                                            <li className='list-group-item list-group-item-success'>
                                                <table className='table table-striped table-hover'>
                                                    <thead className="bg-dark text-white text-center">
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <th>Image</th>
                                                            <th>Name</th>
                                                            <th>Size</th>
                                                            <th>Price</th>
                                                            <th>Qty</th>
                                                            <th>Total</th>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </thead>
                                                    <tbody className='text-center'>
                                                        {cartItems && cartItems.map(item =>{
                                                            return (
                                                                <tr key = {item._id}>
                                                                    <td><img src = {item.image} alt ='' width = {50} height={50}/></td>
                                                                    <td>{item.name}</td>                                                                    
                                                                    <td>{item.size}</td>
                                                                    <td>&#8377; {Number(item.price).toFixed(2)}</td>
                                                                    <td>{item.qty}</td>
                                                                    <td>{Number(Number(item.qty) * Number(item.price)).toFixed(2)}</td>                                                                   
                                                                </tr>
                                                            )}
                                                        )}
                                                    </tbody>
                                                </table>
                                            </li>                                        
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div className="card">
                                    <div className="card-header bg-dark text-white text-center">
                                        <p className='fw-bold'>PROCEED CHECK-OUT</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="card-body">
                                        <ul className='list-group'>
                                            <li  className='list-group-item'>Total Amount: <span className='fw-bold'>&#8377; {Number(totalAmount()).toFixed(2)}</span></li>
                                            <li  className='list-group-item'>Total Tax: <span className='fw-bold'>&#8377; {Number(taxAmount).toFixed(2)}</span></li>
                                            <li  className='list-group-item'>GrandTotal: <span className='fw-bold'>&#8377; {grandTotal().toFixed(2)}</span></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                    {                                   
                                        <div className="card-footer d-flex justify-content-between">
                                            <NavLink to='/orders/cart' className='btn btn-success btn-sm'>Back</NavLink>
                                            <StripeCheckout 
                                                token={handleToken}
                                                billingAddress                
                                                stripeKey={reactstripeKey?reactstripeKey:''}
                                                currency = 'INR'
                                                description = 'Make payment with stripe'
                                                name= 'Stripe Payment'
                                                amount = {grandTotal() * 100}                                 
                                                zipCode
                                                image={stripeImage}
                                                panelLabel = 'pay {{amount}}'>                                        
                                                <button className="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Pay  &#8377; {grandTotal().toFixed(2)}</button>
                                            </StripeCheckout>
                                        </div>
                                    }
                                </div>             
                            </div>                                       
                    </div>
                </div>            
            </section>            
        </React.Fragment>
    )
};
export default CheckOutPage;
```

Since I am using redux, I am calling axios here:
so my orderActions file contains the makeStripePayment method:

```
    //private request
export const makestripePayment = (body:any,order:any, history:any)=>{
    return async (dispatch:any)=>{
        try{
            dispatch({type : STRIPE_PAYMENT_REQUEST});
            let token = UserService.getTokenkey();
            if(token){ 
                TokenServices.settokenVerifier(token);     
                TokenServices.setStripeApiKey(); //setting the bearer token
                let dataUrl:string = `${SERVER_URL}/api/v1/payments/checkout`;
                let response = await axios.post(dataUrl,body);                        
                dispatch({type:STRIPE_PAYMENT_SUCCESS, payload: response.data});
                dispatch(alertActions.showAlert('bg-primary', 'Payment Successfull !!', 'fa-check-circle')); //success alert
                // place an order
                dispatch(placeOrder(order));
                history.push('/users/orderList');
            }         
        }
        catch(error){                     
            dispatch({type:STRIPE_PAYMENT_FAILURE, payload: {error: error}});
            dispatch(alertActions.showAlert('bg-danger', 'Payment Failed !!', 'fa-exclamation-circle')); //failure alert               
        }
    }
}
```

```
    export class TokenServices{

    //set headers value for [x-auth-token] while sending request to the server
    public static settokenVerifier = (token:string) =>{
        if(token){
            axios.defaults.headers['x-auth-token'] = token;
        }
        else{
            delete axios.defaults.headers['x-auth-token'];
        }
    }

    //set headers value for [Authorization] while sending request to the server
    public static setStripeApiKey (){
            axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${process.env.REACT_APP_STRIPE_KEY}`;
    }
}
```

```
    //client env file: (replaced test API key with * for posting here)
REACT_APP_SERVER_URL=http://127.0.0.1:5000
REACT_APP_TOKEN_KEY=react-test-key
REACT_APP_STRIPE_KEY=pk_test_*******

//Server env file: (replaced test API key and mongoUrl with * for posting here)
MONGO_DB_URL=mongodb+srv:**********
JWT_SECRET_KEY=Secret_Login_Key
STRIPE_SECRET_KEY=sk_test_*******
```

Comment: Are you sure that `process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY` is defined in your `PaymentRouter.ts` file? Have you tried logging it?

Comment: No, haven't tried to log it, thanks will do that and update

Comment: @Jonathan Steele I logged process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY and its coming correctly. Do you suggest anything else ?